# Order of declaration in an anonymous pl/sql block

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have an anonymous pl/sql block with a procedure declared inside of it as well as a cursor.  If I declare the procedure before the cursor it fails.  Is there a requirement that cursors be declared prior to procedures?

What other rules are there for order of declaration in a pl/sql block?

This works:

```
DECLARE
 cursor cur is select 1 from dual;
 procedure foo as begin null; end foo;
BEGIN
 null;
END;
```

This fails with error `PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CURSOR" when expecting one of the following: begin function package pragma procedure form`

```
DECLARE
 procedure foo as begin null; end foo;
 cursor cur is select 1 from dual;
BEGIN
 null;
END;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Cursors, variables, constants and types need to be declared before packages/functions.

This one would fail too:

```
DECLARE
 procedure foo as begin null; end foo;
 x VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
 null;
END;
```

Comment: The documentation reference is here
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/block.htm#i32791

It isn't very clear, but "item declarations" (eg variables) are in list 1 and have to come before "procedure/function definitions" which are in list 2.

Comment: So easy to miss when modifying your code! I had a function declared before a cursor and I was getting this: ORA-06550: line XXX, column X:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CURSOR" when expecting one of the following:
begin function pragma procedure

Answer (score 0):

If you want to declare a cursor that is available to the sub procedure as well, just add another anonymous block:

```
DECLARE
 cursor cur is select 1 from dual;
BEGIN
 DECLARE
  procedure foo as begin null; end foo;
 BEGIN
  null;
 END;
END;
```